# Multipolygon to Points

Tags: qgis, polygon, centroids, multi-polygon

I'm currently mapping out around 10 layers worth of polygons all in a polygon feature as shown in the image below.

[image]

I'm now trying to create a heatmap for each layer to show where lies the highest density of the polygons. However, to my understanding it only works with points. My question is how do I convert a multi-polygon feature into coloured centroids for each layer. I've tried the centroid feature but it only creates one colour for all years whereas I want one colour for each layer.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: I'm using QGIS.

Comment: (Looks like one layer with 12 symbol categories)

Answer (score 2):

Here are tools that can help with this task and proposed workflow:

1. [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)
2. [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer)
3. [Centroids](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#centroids) TIP: Pay attention to the option `Create centroid for each part`.